# Linking dialogflow with Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created a working webhook on DialogFlow ES in order to get my solar production with an HTTP requets on my solar edge API.

It's perfectly working on DialogFlow but I'm completely unable to make it work with Google Assistant.

Could somebody help me?

Thanks a lot !!

```json
{
  "responseId": "057d13b6-22c7-4951-94be-28d6f5c5ab34-3a30f4d6",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "Quelle est ma production actuelle?",
    "parameters": {
      "geo-city": "",
      "location": "",
      "date-time": {
        "date_time": "2023-10-17T10:54:01+02:00"
      }
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "La production d'énergie actuelle est de 1001.6812 watts.",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "La production d'énergie actuelle est de 1001.6812 watts."
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/solar-edge-notifications/locations/europe-west1/agent/intents/22fc96c5-68ed-4d07-83ac-30af0a34e5da",
      "displayName": "getSolarData"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.68192226,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 2921
    },
    "languageCode": "fr",
    "sentimentAnalysisResult": {
      "queryTextSentiment": {}
    }
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "message": "Webhook execution successful"
  },
  "agentId": "c5fdd86d-6185-4de0-b77c-ce1394edc722"
}

{
  "responseId": "057d13b6-22c7-4951-94be-28d6f5c5ab34-3a30f4d6",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "Quelle est ma production actuelle?",
    "parameters": {
      "date-time": {
        "date_time": "2023-10-17T10:54:01+02:00"
      },
      "location": "",
      "geo-city": ""
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/solar-edge-notifications/locations/europe-west1/agent/sessions/f2156d38-71ad-b60f-1cb2-cf98d20d5d05/contexts/__system_counters__",
        "parameters": {
          "no-input": 0,
          "no-match": 0,
          "date-time": {
            "date_time": "2023-10-17T10:54:01+02:00"
          },
          "date-time.original": "actuelle",
          "location": "",
          "location.original": "",
          "geo-city": "",
          "geo-city.original": ""
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/solar-edge-notifications/locations/europe-west1/agent/intents/22fc96c5-68ed-4d07-83ac-30af0a34e5da",
      "displayName": "getSolarData"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.68192226,
    "languageCode": "fr"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE",
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "projects/solar-edge-notifications/locations/europe-west1/agent/sessions/f2156d38-71ad-b60f-1cb2-cf98d20d5d05"
}

{
  "fulfillmentText": "La production d'énergie actuelle est de 1001.6812 watts.",
  "outputContexts": []
}
```

Webhook execution successful

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your Dialogflow ES webhook works with Google Assistant, there are two approaches:

1. **Dialogflow ES Console**: Modify the intent’s responses using [rich messages](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#add) formats.
2. **Direct JSON Handling**: Update the JSON to include Google Assistant-specific formats.

   - [simple responses](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/simple-responses)
   - [rich responses](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/rich-responses).

   ```json
   "fulfillmentMessages": [
     {
       "platform": "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE",
       "simpleResponses": {
         "simpleResponses": [
           {
             "textToSpeech": "La production d'énergie actuelle est de 1001.6812 watts."
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   ]
   ```